# Appo Deepo Bhava or Atta dīpo bhava | Which is the correct wording?

Tags: secular-buddhism

I was looking for some good Buddha Quote and I find this very interesting. ' **Be light of yourself**.  But I found two versions of this  in google as

1. Appo Deepo Bhava
2. Atta dīpo bhava

Which one is the correct wording? I would like to get the proper Pali wordings for the phrase " **Be light to yourself**".

thank you

Comment: I think that's addressed at the linked topic -- *Attadīpā*